# Hide credentials for all projects in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, bintray

My private repo which is loaded from bintray used for all projects and needs credentials:

```
allprojects {
     jcenter()
     repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://myurl.bintray.com/sdk"
            credentials {
                username 'JohnDoe'
                password 'somePassword'
            }
        }
     }     
}
```

What's the best way to hide them?

Is it possible without creating new instance of Properties?

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to set properties in the user specific file `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`:

```
thePassword=somePassword
```

and in the build.gradle file:

```
credentials {
    username 'JohnDoe'
    password thePassword
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Repositories{

maven{
name='tomRepo'
url=''
credentials(PasswordCredentials)
}
}
```

run a command in the console like this

```
./gradlew build --refresh-dependecies -PtomsRepoUsername=aws -PtomRepoPassword=$TOMS_REPO_PASSWORD
```